# Use GroupBy on ListItemCollection using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, linq

I am trying to do a GroupBy on a bunch of items that I have retrieved using CSOM and when I try do a foreach loop to go through them I get method not supported exception.

```
List contactsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Contacts List");
CamlQuery contactsQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(5000, new []{"ID", "Full_x0020_Name"});
ListItemCollection contactItemsCollection = contactsList.GetItems(contactsQuery);
context.Load(contactItemsCollection);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

and then group them

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<object, ListItem>> groupItems = contactItemsCollection.Where(i => i.FieldValues["Full_x0020_Name"] != null).GroupBy(item => item.FieldValues["Full_x0020_Name"]);
```

and then when I try to iterate through them

```
foreach (var groupItem in groupItems)
{
}

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Specified method is not supported.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
```

Regards.

Comment: check this on http://www.acnenomor.com/1579496p1/iqueryablegroupby-override-throws-for-int-and-bool-but-not-for-strings

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs since in SharePoint 2010 CSOM (V14) `Where` and `GroupBy` operators are not supported.

**Solution**

Replace the line:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<object, ListItem>> groupItems = contactItemsCollection.Where(i => i.FieldValues["Full_x0020_Name"] != null).GroupBy(item => item.FieldValues["Full_x0020_Name"]);
```

with this one:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, ListItem>> groupItems = contactItemsCollection.ToList().Where(i => i.FieldValues["Full_x0020_Name"] != null).GroupBy(item => item.FieldValues["Full_x0020_Name"]);
```

Comment: hi Vadim, am looking for csom c, how to check for duplicates in my SPO environment.. how to get those duplicate listitems..